# Clip_analysis producing an extra output in Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, clip

I am trying to clip a feature class of floodplain polygons using another polygon object in arcpy, like so:

```
arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features = floodplain_polys, 
                    clip_features = <PolygonObject>, 
                    out_feature_class = path.join(scratch_gdb, 'test'))
```

The clip runs fine, but it creates *two* outputs: one called `test`, and another called `floodplain_polys_Clip`, both in the same fgdb. I know that the second name is the default output name for a Clip analysis, but I'm struggling to figure out why it's created in the first place. Is this happening because I used a Polygon Object instead of another feature class? If so, why?

Comment: Please provide a code snippet that shows how you set `floodplain_polys` and `scratch_gdb`, and how you created your Polygon object.  Without that you are asking us to try and debug a copy/paste of a line of code rather than a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312).

Comment: When I tested on a polygon layer, a polygon object and a file gdb, the result is as expected. No two outputs.

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried it again and I also did not get two outputs. Perhaps the first time was an anomaly.